# Jump to a specific page of a PDF in an iFrame

Tags: jquery, pdf, iframe

I had a requirement to open a specific page of a PDF file, which is within an iframe.

There were lot of solutions, but nothing seem to work. Here are a few:

1. Using PDFViewer aplication

```
function goToPage(desiredPage){
var frame_1 = window.frames["iframe-name"];
var frameObject = document.getElementById("iframe-id").contentWindow;
frameObject.PDFViewerApplication.page = desired page;
}
```

2. Using PostMessage

```
message = "data";
iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');  
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*');
```

3. URL modification

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.exampleurl.com/file.pdf#page=4">
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what has worked for me. I hope it helps.

```html
var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
iframe.style.display = visibility;   
setTimeout(function () { iframe.src = ''+document_source+'#page=' + pageNumber }, 0);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).